# How to convert source code from latex to lyx?

Tags: lyx

I have difficulties to make poster in lyx. I found some source codes to make poster in latex like .txt and .sty in this homepage http://fuse.pha.jhu.edu/~wolven/posters.html. I want to put this codes in lyx editor and see the result as a Pdf or dvi. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg06958.html) seems to indicate that it would be quite difficult to incorporate that class into Lyx. [Beamerposter](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php) is an extension of the Beamer class which might help, and their [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/beamerposter?pli=1) would be a good place to ask about using it in Lyx.